# How to connect with PowerShell using external user creds to another tenant in Azure?

Tags: powershell, azure, external

I have "external user" from TenantA AD added to TenantB in Azure and added as "owner" to one of B subscriptions.

How can I connect with PowerShell using that external user to TenantB subscription?

`Login-AzureRmAccount`/`Add-AzureRmAccount` while using external users' UPN in `-Credential` and specifying tenantId/subscriptionId of TenantB gives me error:

> add-azurermaccount : The provided account <...> does not have access to subscription ID "<...>". Please try logging in with
>   different credentials or a different subscription ID.**

Looking at `Get-MsolUser` output of TenantB, I can see external user from tenantA in the following form:

```
PS C:\> get-msoluser

UserPrincipalName                                                          DisplayName     isLicensed
-----------------                                                          -----------     ----------
<username>_tenantA.onmicrosoft.com#EXT#@tenantB.onmicrosoft.com  <..>   False
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with clearing the cached credentials using:

```
Get-AzureAccount | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureAccount $_.ID -Force }
```

Then use `Login-AzureRmAccount` and enter the credentials for *TenantA*. You should be able to switch the subscription using.

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName
```

Comment: Thanks.
unfortunately, logging in with TenantA creds and trying to switch to a subscription in TenantB using -SubscriptionId and -TenantId gives this error:

Select-AzureRmSubscription : Provided subscription <...> does not exist


I suspect Select-AzureRmsubscription is looking for subscription in TenantA as I can verify I'm in the context of TenantA by using Get-AzureRmTenant.

Comment: If you log in into the portal using TeantA creds, can you see the TeanantB subscription?

Comment: While in tenantA's Azure portal I'm not seeing TenantB's subscription I have "Owner" access to. 
Btw, I just doublechecked that permission is there on the subscription in question by running Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment and getting my external user listed there as: 
SignInName         : user_tenantA.onmicrosoft.com#EXT#@tenantB.onmicrosoft.com
RoleDefinitionName : Owner